# Why does fgetpos() return a negative offset?

Tags: c

When I am using `fgetpos(fp,&pos)`, the call is setting `pos` to a negative value where `pos` is of type `fpos_t`. Can some one explain why this is happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define MAX_TAG_LEN 50

char filename[1000] = "d:\\ire\\a.xml";

//extract each tag from the xml file
int getTag(char * tag, FILE *fp)
{
    //skip until a beginning of a next
    while(!feof(fp))
        if((char)fgetc(fp) == '<')break;

    if(!feof(fp)){
        char temp[MAX_TAG_LEN]={0};
        char *ptr;
        int len;
        fpos_t b;
        fgetpos(fp,&b);   // here the b is containing -ve values.....???
        fread(temp,sizeof(char),MAX_TAG_LEN - 1,fp);
        temp[MAX_TAG_LEN-1] = 0;
        ptr = strchr(temp,'>');  //search of ending tag bracket
        len = ptr - temp + 1;
        sprintf(tag,"<%.*s",len,temp); //copy the tag
        printf("%s",tag); //print the tag
        b += len;         //reset the position of file pointer to just after the tag character.
        fsetpos(fp,&b);

        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int ch;
    char tag[100]={0};
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");

    while(getTag(tag,fp)){
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

where a.xml is a very basic xml file

```
<file>
  <page>
    <title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect />
    <revision>
      <id>133452289</id>
      <timestamp>2007-05-25T17:12:12Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Gurch</username>
        <id>241822</id>
      </contributor>
      <minor />
      <comment>Revert edit(s) by [[Special:Contributions/Ngaiklin|Ngaiklin]] to last version by [[Special:Contributions/Rory096|Rory096]]</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Computer accessibility]] {{R from CamelCase}}</text>
    </revision>
  </page>

  </file>
```

The code is working for some xml files but for the above xml file it is stoping after printing the first  tag.

Comment: please post the full code you are using to fpos

Answer (score 9):

According to [the cplusplus.com description of `fpos_t`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fpos_t/):

> `fpos_t` objects are usually created by a call to `fgetpos`, which returns a reference to an object of this type.  The content of a `fpos_t` is not meant to be read directly, but only to use its reference as an argument in a call to `fsetpos`.

I think that means that in theory the value of an `fpos_t` could be arbitrarily positive or negative, so long as the implementation treats it correctly.  For example, `fpos_t` could be some offset from the *end* of the file rather than the beginning, in which case negative values make sense.  It also could be some weird bit-packed representation that would use each bit, including the sign bit, to encode some other information about the file position.

Comment: Right `fpos_t` is an *opaque type* just like `FILE` is, you're never supposed to actually try to access its innards because they are implementation defined. +1

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the error....

msdn says

> You can use fseek to reposition the
>   pointer anywhere in a file. The
>   pointer can also be positioned beyond
>   the end of the file. fseek clears the
>   end-of-file indicator and negates the
>   effect of any prior ungetc calls
>   against stream.
>
> When a file is opened for appending
>   data, the current file position is
>   determined by the last I/O operation,
>   not by where the next write would
>   occur. If no I/O operation has yet
>   occurred on a file opened for
>   appending, the file position is the
>   start of the file.
>
> **For streams opened in text mode, fseek has limited use, because
>   carriage return–linefeed translations
>   can cause fseek to produce unexpected
>   results.** The only fseek operations
>   guaranteed to work on streams opened
>   in text mode are:
>
> Seeking with an offset of 0 relative
>   to any of the origin values. Seeking
>   from the beginning of the file with an
>   offset value returned from a call to
>   ftell.

once fopen call is modified from "r" to "rb" it worked fine....

thanks